# recreate page/list view after navigation.PushAsync Xamarin.forms

Tags: c#, listview, xamarin.forms

I am making Dark Mode & I have those problem:

I have listView and settings button on toolbar:[image: dark_mode]

When I switch ThemeMode 
[image: Theme_switch]
Theme doesn't switch, but when I navigate to other Page and then return to Main_Menu I have this problem:

[image: Problem]

When I restart app, it's all right.

How can I refresh page/listView ?
PLease help!
Thanks everyone!

Comment: Can you share your code? I used this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42997914/xamarin-forms-switching-between-dark-light-themes-at-run-time to set the dark mode, it is running normally.

Comment: Is that code working onAppearing()???

Comment: @LeonLu-MSFT thanks for instructions. I made it! *marking as solution *

Comment: I made a conslusion about dark mode, pleaes mark it answer, it will help others who have similar issue.Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to acheved dark mode in your app, you can use these packages.

Xamarin.Forms.Themes.Base, 
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Forms.Theme.Base/

Xamarin.Forms.Themes.Dark
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Forms.Theme.Dark/1.0.0.43-pre1

Add follow code in your **App.xaml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Application 
xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
xmlns:light="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms.Themes;assembly=Xamarin.Forms.Theme.Light"
xmlns:dark="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms.Themes;assembly=Xamarin.Forms.Theme.Dark"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
x:Class="MyNamespace.MyApp">
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary MergedWith="light:LightThemeResources">
        ...
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```